# BeautifulSoup can't read HTML of the webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get real estate data from https://www.realtor.com/

I use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

main_url='https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/New-York_NY'

page=requests.get(main_url).content
bs(page,'html.parser')
```

It does not output the full HTML of the page, so can't find the tags I am interested in.

**Is there another way to get the full HTML?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping Dynamic website using beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732931/scraping-dynamic-website-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score -2):

```
import requests

main_url='https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/New-York_NY'

page=requests.get(main_url)
results = bs(page.content,'html.parser')
print(results)
```

This should work